# Why did Community add the algebraic geometry tag to my question?

Tags: support, tagging, community-user

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/694783/53776) is the question.

I'm not complaining, I'm just curious why it happened.

Answer (score 4):

If you click the word "edited", you get the question's revision history. From there, click "Suggested" to get the history of [that particular suggested edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/172744). It says:

> proposed 11 hours ago by an anonymous user

and gives some other details of the process, including the edit statistics of said anonymous user.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure it means that an unregistred user suggested the tag addition and someone (with sufficiently high reputation) approved the suggestion.